# excluding meaningful zeros as robustness check in FE OLS?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, residuals, fixed-effects-model

I'm estimating a regression utilizing power plant data and drought data. A lot of the generators contain (meaningful) 0 values.
I utilize a IHS tranformation and my main regression residuals can be seen (for a single powerplant) on the top left.
To check my results I am also running an analysis where I exclude the 0s, my rationale for this is, because I cannot be sure whether the zero was caused by drought or by e.g. maintenance work.

Is this a valid robustness check? The coefficients are slightly smaller in magnitude when i exclude the zeros, thus I would say, if there is an omitted variable bias due to e.g. maintenance, there would be an upward bias?

[image]

Comment: What is an IHS transform?

Comment: inverse hyperbolic sine, similar to log but defined for zeros